# 'verb-ing' or 'to verb' after the verb 'continue'?

Tags: difference, usage, infinitive-vs-gerund

Which form of the verb is correct after the verb "continue"?

> If police didn't arrest him, he would continue robbing.
>   If police didn't arrest him, he would continue to rob.
>   <sub>(These sentences are written by me.)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Both forms are accepted, although if you're still learning, and didn't make it a habit, the '-ing' form is less ambiguous.

The problem is that the '*verb* to *verb*' in some contexts may mean two different things.

> I stopped smoking

It means unambiguously that I don't smoke (cigarettes or whatever) any more.

> I was raking dry leaves all morning, and while doing it, I came to a life-changing decision. I stopped to smoke, and decided to quit my current job and take up a hobby.

And here we don't know: was the decision to stop smoking? Or - conversely - he stopped raking leaves, in order to smoke a cigarette, and then, while smoking, came up with the remaining decisions.

In other words, the negatives - 'stop', 'pause', 'cease', etc connected with 'to *verb*' may relate either to stopping/pausing/etc that specific activity, or pausing a previous activity, in order to start the given activity!

The '-ing' bears no such ambiguity and is equally valid as a grammar construct, so if you have no specific reasons for writing otherwise, '-ing' is safer.

Comment: "Stopped" isn't the best example here; "stopped to smoke" never means anything other than "took a break in order to begin smoking", at least in my native AmE.