# Verb + to or -ing

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

My question is about these verbs:

> **like
>
>   love
>
>   start
>
>   prefer
>
>   hate
>
>   begin
>
>   continue**

When they are followed by another verb we can use **to** or the **gerund** (**-ing**):

> I prefer **to** travel by car. ***- or -*** I prefer **travelling** by car.
>   Anna loves **to** dance. ***- or -*** Anna loves **dancing**
>   Do you like **to** get up early? ***- or -*** Do you like **getting** up early?

My grammar book says that we can use either **to** or **-ing** whithout changing the meaning. 

(It also says that there are the exceptions of *would like, would love, would hate* or *would prefer*: they must be followed by **to**. e.g. *Julia would like **to** meet you.*)

1) Is there any subtle difference between the usage of **to** or **-ing** after these verbs?
 2) Do you thing that using **-ing** is safer? (as written in [this wonderful answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26551/verb-ing-or-to-verb-after-the-verb-continue) to somebody else's question)

Comment: In your '1)' you say, "in this context".  Which context do you mean?

Comment: Yes, maybe is too ambiguous. I will change it. Thank you!

Comment: As you have it, I read almost no subtle differences between your examples.  The -ing ending might slightly convey that the active act (the doing part of the verb) is more important than the verb itself, but that may be me reading further into your question than I would otherwise.  Good question.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Thank you very much for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the gerund and infinitive forms are interchangeable; sometimes they are not. Your examples above ("travelling", "dancing", "getting") are all examples of interchangeable usage. Here are examples where interchanging alters the meaning of the sentence:

"Travelling" vs "to travel":

- He remembered **travelling** to Canada. (He has traveled to Canada, and
  now remembers that.)
- He remembered **to travel** to Canada. (He was supposed to go to Canada, and then he did.)

"Dancing" vs "to dance":

- She stopped **dancing**. (She never danced again.)
- She stopped **to dance**. (She interrupted an activity to begin dancing.)

How do you know when the gerund and infinitive are interchangeable? Generally, gerunds are best for talking about completed actions, and infinitives are best for talking about incomplete or future actions.

**Gerund:** I was **getting up** earlier last week. (The *getting up* already heppened.)

**Infinitive:** I want **to get up** earlier. (The *getting up* hasn't happened yet.)

Still, knowing which form to use requires some memorization and intuition. Here is a list of common verbs from http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/gerunds-and-infinitives/:

**Followed by a gerund:**

admit, advise, avoid, be, used to, can’t help, can’t stand, consider, deny, discuss, dislike, end up, enjoy, feel like, finish, forget, get used to, give up, go on, have difficulty, have problems, have trouble, imagine, it’s no use, it’s worthwhile, keep, look forward to, mention, mind, miss, recommend, remember, quit, spend time, stop, suggest, understand, waste time, work at

**Followed by either a gerund or an infinitive without causing a change in meaning:**

begin, continue, hate, intend, like, love, prefer, start

**Followed by a gerund or infinitive but with a change in meaning:**

forget, remember, stop

**Followed by an infinitive:**

afford, agree, appear, arrange, ask, care, decide, demand, expect, fail, forget, hope, learn, manage, mean, offer, plan, prepare, pretend, promise, refuse, remember, seem, stop, volunteer, wait, want, wish

**Followed by a noun or pronoun and then by an infinitive:**

advise, allow, ask, cause, challenge, command, convince, expect, forbid, force, hire, instruct, invite, order, pay, permit, program, remind, teach, tell, urge, want, warn

Comment: "He remember to travel to Canada." Isn't correct.

Comment: @RileyFrancisco Right, that is not correct. The verb "remember" needs a tense to be used in that format, e.g."remembers", "remembered", or "will remember".

Answer (score 2):

There are lists of verbs telling you whether to use the infinitive or —*ing* form. I suggest not to memorise them. You'll learn to use the infinitive or —*ing* as part of phrases, mostly.

Here I'll highlight some examples where the difference in meaning is greatly noticed.

> *Have you **tried changing** your diet?* (Have you experimented different foods?)
>   *Have you **tried to change** your diet?* (Have you made an effort to change what you eat?)
>
> ---
>
> *I **stopped asking** him about his son.* (I didn't ask any more questions about his son.)
>   *I **stopped to ask** him about his son.* (I stopped what I was doing because I wanted to ask him about his son.)
>
> ---
>
> *Please **remember to switch** the lights off.* (Don't forget to do this.)
>   *I **remember switching** the lights off*. (I've done this and I remember this fact.)

So it's not that —*ing* forms show you a *safer* way to write this. You'll see difference in meaning anyway regarding the verb.

Of course a good point to always keep in mind is not to use the **state verbs** with —*ing* forms. (You can as long as they describe an action, but that's another topic.)