# Continue to provoke vs continue provoking

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Do both forms of the verb "continue" have the same meaning in these sentences? Did I even use "to continue" correctly?

> He taunts the player from the opposing team. Since he did not react, he continues provoking him but goes too far.

> He taunts the player from the opposing team. Since he did not react, he continues to provoke him but goes too far.

Comment: One of these probably answers your question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26551/verb-ing-or-to-verb-after-the-verb-continue?r=SearchResults&s=1|41.2378 https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60898/whats-the-difference-between-continues-doing-and-continues-to-do?r=SearchResults&s=3|28.4092